# Link that scrolls to position

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Is it possible to create a link to any web page and scroll to the position of the first instance of a block of text?

eg:

```
http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/06/google-api-launch-still-months-away/#scrollto"A Google project headed by Vic Gundotra"
```

and this will scroll to some where half way of the page.

Note: I don't have control over the linked page, it could be any page on the web. Is there any javascript trick that will allow me to do what I described?

Answer (score 4):

> I don't have control of the linked page

All you can do is link to an anchor/ID on the page. If the first block of text on the targeted page has an ID attribute, then you can link to that:

```
wwww.example.com/page.html#blockOfTextID
```

Comment: I already know this. thanks anyway. the problem is I don't have control over the linked page (it could be any page on the web)

Comment: Right. Well, that's all you can do.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only link to parts of the page that already have named anchors on the page.

[Link that scrolls to position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324412/link-that-scrolls-to-position/#7324427)

Which links to my answer to your question. But only works, because Stack Overflow has HTML like:

```
<a name="7324427"></a>
```

Above every answer to make this possible.

Comment: Is there any javascript trick that will allow me to do what I described?

Comment: It's not your page. Therefore, you can't run any JS on it.

Comment: what about putting it into an iframe and scroll that? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you're looking for is a Text Fragment:

[Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/)

I know this is an old question, but the answers pre-date this technology, and I was researching a similar issue and noticed this came up as a top result.